# how to fix the "speed bump" sign in windows pop up

Tags: windows, sign, auto, unlock, credential-providers

want to implement an auto unlock credential.

I used the SampleV2CredentialProvider demo, and wrote the account password in the "CSampleCredential::Initialize" as follow

hr = SHStrDupW(L"mypassword", &_rgFieldStrings[SFI_PASSWORD]);

and change the *pAutoLogin= true in SetSelected.

however the "sign in" window pop up, I couldn't directly login in the system without click the button.

I also changed the *pbAutoLogonWithDefault = true in the CSampleProvider::GetCredentialCount, but the button still pop up.

Comment: Do you forget to fill the `pdwDefault` output parameter with proper value?

Comment: I filled the value as   *pdwDefault = DWORD(0);

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked code of one of my Credential Providers.
Inside of `ICredentialProvider::GetCredentialCount` method I do the following:

```
DWORD dwSize;

*pdwCount = 0;
*pdwDefault = -1;
*pbAutoLogonWithDefault = FALSE;
dwSize = 0;

// do some internal calculations

if(dwSize > 0)
{
    *pdwCount = 1;
    *pdwDefault = 0;
    *pbAutoLogonWithDefault = TRUE;
}
```

Iside of `ICredentialProviderCredential::SetSelected` i do only this:

```
*pbAutoLogon = TRUE;
```

Everything is working fine.
(The code snippets are exactly copy-paste from real project)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   where you declare dwSize.? my code works fine in the physical machine. while in the VR machine, "sign in"  Pop up still there.

Comment: `dwSize` is my intrenal variable for evaluating decision - to do AutoLogon or not to do. My solution works fine on both physical machines and virtual machines. I have just fixed my code snippet.